# Access current theme face attributes in init.el

Tags: init-file, faces, themes

I have these lines in my init.el:

```
(load-theme 'wombat)
(deftheme wombat)
...
(defvar my/default-cursor-color (face-attribute 'cursor :background t))
```

I want the variable `my/default-cursor-color` to be `#656565` as defined in wombat theme. However, after opening emacs it is equal to `unspecified`.
I tried to change the last line to

```
(defvar my/default-cursor-color (face-attribute 'cursor :background)
```

but in this case the value of `my/default-cursor-color` is `white`.

It is important to note that I run emacs as a daemon.

How to access the current theme face attributes in init.el?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: IIUC, `deftheme` is only used when you define a theme (e.g. in the `wombat-theme.el` file). You should delete it from your init file.

Comment: What happens if you say `(face-attribute 'cursor :background nil 'default)`? BTW, have you tried evaluating `(load-theme 'wombat)` by hand? Does that succeed?

Comment: @NickD `(face-attribute 'cursor :background nil 'default)` returns `#656565`, cursor doesn't change. `(load-theme 'wombat)` returns `t`.

Comment: @NickD I noticed that with minimal init.el
`(load-theme 'wombat)
(defvar my/default-cursor-color (face-attribute 'cursor :background))`
I have `my/default-cursor-color` equal to `#656565` as expected. I will try to find out what's wrong with my main config.

Comment: @NickD I guess the main point is that normally I start emacs as a daemon, but in the last case (with the minimal config) I strarted it by `emacs -q -l init-test.el`.

Comment: A possible workaround is to use this to lines:
`(defvar my/default-cursor-color nil)
(add-hook 'server-after-make-frame-hook
          (lambda () (setq my/default-cursor-color (face-attribute 'cursor :background))))`
in place of `(defvar my/default-cursor-color (face-attribute 'cursor :background))`